How get three base plots with miniplot inside on one panel with different widths?
Using layout, I can easily create panels.
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
layout(matrix(1:3, nrow=1), widths=c(.8, 1.1, .8))
plot(1:20, 1:20, pch=19, cex=2, col=colfunc(20))
plot(1:20, 1:20, pch=19, cex=2, col=colfunc(20))
plot(1:20, 1:20, pch=19, cex=2, col=colfunc(20))
par(op)


However, when creating a plot with miniplot inside, such as a gradient,
plotfun <- \() {
  colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))
  plot(1:20, 1:20, pch=19, cex=2, col=colfunc(20))
  fig. <- c(grconvertX(c(.1, 5), from="user", to="ndc"), 
            grconvertY(c(8, 19), from="user", to="ndc"))
  op <- par(fig=fig., mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1), new=TRUE)
  plot.window(c(0, 1), c(0, 1))
  rasterImage(as.raster(matrix(colfunc(20), ncol=1)), 0, 0, 1, 1)
  lbsq <- seq.int(0, 1, l=5)
  axis(4, at=lbsq, pos=0, labels=FALSE, col=0, col.ticks=1, tck=-.1)
  mtext(lbsq, 4, .5, at=lbsq, las=2, cex=.6)
  mtext('foo', 3, 0, cex=.6, adj=.5, font=2)
  par(op)
}

it leaves the layout.
op <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
layout(matrix(1:3, nrow=1), widths=c(.8, 1.1, .8))
plotfun()
plotfun()
plotfun()
par(op)


I'm aware that layout is "totally incompatible with ... par(mfrow)". But I already tried par() which also didn't work. Anyway I need something like layout since I have different widths. Any clues, how to do it?

Maybe try the 3rd base option, split.screen?

@ Can we have varying widths? I've read that split.screen is also incompatible w/ layout.

Yes, they're incompatible, but split.screen is the most flexible of the three options (mfrow/mfol layout, and split screen). If I remember right (it's been at least 10 years since I used it) with a matrix input you can define "screens" at any rectangles within the plotting device, you just provide the coordinates of two opposite corners. And since screens can be split into subscreens, you can have inset plots, overlapping plots, etc.

My guess is that your plotfun gets the gradient in there by using split.screen  (internally to one of the functions it uses), which is in fact why it's incompatible with your layout attempt. Since screen splitting can be nested, hopefully it will work here.

@GregorThomas Thanks for your hints, after a little getting used to it, it works quite well!

We can use split.screen() with a matrix in the figs= argument. To obtain similar segmentation as in layout, we calculate the cumsum of the widths=, that we first precede with a zero and normalize to get "nfc',
> c(0, c(.8, 1.1, .8)) |> cumsum() |> normalize() |> round(1)
[1] 0.0 0.3 0.7 1.0

and make a matrix out of it, as nicely explained in this answer.
> split.screen(matrix(c(0, .3, .7, 
+                       .3, .7, 1, 
+                       0, 0, 0, 
+                       1, 1, 1), 3))
[1] 7 8 9
> screen(1)
> plotfun()
> screen(2)
> plotfun()
> screen(3)
> plotfun()


We can still use things like par(mar=) in the individual plots.
